# Problems building project with .c and .s

Tags: atmel

I'm using Atmel Studio to program my board

I have a solution open with 2 projects as ".c"  I have created the proper dependencies for the projects but one of the include files is a ".h" and uses a ".s" to define its functions... how can I make this build work?

The .S and .h files are inside the include folder.

The error I get is:

> undefined reference to "function_foo"

which is in declared in .h but the .s is defined... they aren't linked somehow.

Comment: Erm, no. The .s file needs to be compiled as a separate module and then linked into the rest.

Comment: I crashed atmel... brb restarted program
I still couldn't get it to work... I have to build a solution that uses .C and .S (assembly) and I think the solution doesn't compile because its using to different type of files... yep basically the above^. how can I include it as part of the solution?

Comment: pls respond! How do I add .S file into AtmelStudio6 solutions so it compiles

Comment: Dunno. Never used it.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to rename the .s file to .S to get it to compile in a GCC project. It sounds like the build system is ignoring it and thus not generating any code for the function.

Comment: It's already called ffft.S

Comment: In your question you use a lowercase 's'. It needs to be uppercase. Try posting your project files somewhere so we can take a look.

Comment: IDK how to upload it to github. So I'm not sure how to let you see it...
OR I should say. It's on the window's app. I've committed and push but Idk how to view it online and get a link

Comment: Just upload an archive to MEGA or something.